# How to watch an automatically startet python script on raspberry / raspian?

Tags: python, terminal, process, visible

On my Pi (with the lite text only Linux on it) a Python-Program is started through rc.local! When I log in the (headless) Pi then I do not see the output of the program (simple print-commands). I can see that Python3 is running when I use "pa -S" and "top", but I cannot switch to the output from the program.

How can I make the output visible in the terminal-window like it is when I start the program straight from the command line?

Thanks and cheers,

Ulrich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do that, you must write the output into a file with redirection.
In the rc.local, you can write: `your_program  >> logfile_name  2>&1`
But the logfile must be sometimes deleted.
Search for `[linux] redirection`!